# nomatch in data.table ':' not updating properly

Tags: r, data.table

I am using data,table 1.9.4 with R 3.1.2 Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit). nomatch argument in ':=' functionality doesn't seem to work. Following is the sample code

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.nomatch=0)
dt1 = data.table(
        a=c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 2), 3),
        b=c(1:2, 1:2,1),
        c=101:105)
setkey(dt1, a, b)
dt1

dtw = data.table(a=c(1,3), w1=c(201, 203), w2=c(301,303))
setkey(dtw, a)
dtw

dt1[dtw, ':='(w1=i.w1, w2=i.w2)]
dt1
```

it returns NA in w1 and w2 columns in stead of 0.

```
   a b   c  w1  w2
1: 1 1 101 201 301
2: 1 2 102 201 301
3: 2 1 103  NA  NA
4: 2 2 104  NA  NA
5: 3 1 105 203 303
```

The correct output should be

```
   a b   c  w1  w2
1: 1 1 101 201 301
2: 1 2 102 201 301
3: 2 1 103   0   0
4: 2 2 104   0   0
5: 3 1 105 203 303
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get 0 in stead of NA?

Comment: "*When a row in ‘i’ has no match to ‘x’'s key*", `nomatch` comes into play. In the case of `dt1[dtw]` - as `x[i]` - all the keys in `dtw` ('i') are in `dt1` ('x'). Therefore, `nomatch` never even has an effect. Also, `nomatch=0` doesn't mean 0's are returned, it means "*no rows will be returned for that row of ‘i’.*" Try `dtw[dt1,nomatch=NA]` versus `dtw[dt1,nomatch=0]`

Comment: Though thela is right, this is a still good a question and I agree that `nomatch = 0` could be misleading. Nice question and nice reproducible example.

Comment: @thelatemail: Sorry I have been away, hence couldn't get back. dtw("i") has only 2 keys (1, 3) whereas dt1("x") has 3 keys (1, 2, 3). What I want is update the rows in dt1 for corresponding keys in dtw, return 0 as column values if corresponding dt1 key is not there in dtw.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your misunderstood current `nomatch` behavior, `nomatch=0` doesn't fill with `0`.
Not sure if `nomatch` affects `:=` at all. It is used on join without `:=` to indicate if it should be *inner* or *outer* join.
Be aware the `nomatch` behavior is likely to change in 2.0.0 - quite a distant future as it is 4 stable releases from now.
For reference leaving the current discussion on that change [#857](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/857).